# Nhibernate count distinct (based on multiple columns)

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

Basically, i have been trying to do this (count distinct based on two columns):

```
select count(distinct(checksum(TableA.PropertyA, TableB.PropertyB))) 
from TableA 
left outer join TableB
on TableA.TableBId = TableB.Id 
where PropertyA like '%123%'
```

Been googling on how to do this but with no luck. Tried this, but never actually worked. This does not count distinctly based on the two properties from two tables:

```
var queryOver = c.QueryOver<TableA>();
TableB tableBAlias = null;
TableA tableAAlias = null;
ProjectionList projections = Projections.ProjectionList();

queryOver.AndRestrictionOn(x => x.PropertyA).IsLike("%123%");
projections.Add(Projections.CountDistinct(() => tableAAlias.PropertyA));

queryOver.JoinAlias(x => x.TableB , () => tableBAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
projections.Add(Projections.CountDistinct(() => tableBAlias.PropertyB));

queryOver.Select(projections);
queryOver.UnderlyingCriteria.SetProjection(projections);
return queryOver.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity).RowCount();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay this is going to take a few steps, so bear with me. I'm assuming SQL server here, but the instructions should work for any dialect that supports `checksum`<sup>1</sup>:

1. Create a custom dialect that supports the `checksum` function:

   ```cs
   public class MyCustomDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
   {
       public MyCustomDialect()
       {
           RegisterFunction("checksum", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Int32, "checksum(?1, ?2)"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Update your configuration to use the custom dialect (you can do this either in your configuration XML file or with code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175704/497356) for more information). Here's how I did it inside of my existing configuration code:

   ```cs
   configuration
       .Configure(@"hibernate.cfg.xml")
       .DataBaseIntegration(
           db => db.Dialect<MyCustomDialect>());
   ```
3. Create a custom projection that calls `checksum`. This step is optional-- you can call `Projections.SqlFunction` directly if you'd like, but I think refactoring it into a separate function is cleaner:

   ```cs
   public static class MyProjections 
   {
       public static IProjection Checksum(params IProjection[] projections)
       {
           return Projections.SqlFunction("checksum", NHibernateUtil.Int32, projections);   
       }
   }
   ```
4. Write your QueryOver query and call the custom projection:

   ```cs
   int count = session.QueryOver<TableA>(() => tableAAlias)
       .Where(p => p.PropertyA.IsLike("%123%"))
       .Left.JoinQueryOver(p => p.TableB, () => tableBAlias)
       .Select(
           Projections.Count(
               Projections.Distinct(
               MyProjections.Checksum(
                   Projections.Property(() => tableAAlias.PropertyA),
                   Projections.Property(() => tableBAlias.PropertyB)))))
       .SingleOrDefault<int>();
   ```

   This should generate SQL that looks like what you're after:

   ```sql
   SELECT count(distinct checksum(this_.PropertyA, tableba1_.PropertyB)) as y0_
   FROM   [TableA] this_
       left outer join [TableB] tableba1_
       on this_.TableBId = tableba1_.Id
   WHERE  this_.PropertyA like '%123%' /* @p0 */
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>Still trying to figure out if there's a way to map a function without manually specifying the number of arguments

Comment: RegisterFunction("checksum", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Int32, "checksum(?1, ?2)")) THIS SIR IS AWESOME!