# Using the SQL "IsNull()" command in NHibernate criteria in C#

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I need to be able to use with NHibernate criteria, the SQL's IsNull() function in C#.NET. I don't need to use it with LINQ.
Meaning that Table1 has the following columns:

```
Name | Description
```

Table2 has the following columns:

```
OriginalDescription | TranslatedDescription
```

And `Table1.Description = Table2.OriginalDescription.`
How would I write the following SQL statement with NHibernate criteria:

```
SELECT Table1.Model, IsNull(Table2.TranslatedDescription, Table1.Description)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.OriginalDescription = Table1.Description
```

The SQL statement above will give me the Names, and TranslatedDescriptions if the TranslatedDescriptions exist, otherwise it will return the Descriptions, for the records.
There cannot be duplicates of OriginalDescription in the Table2.

Comment: Does `t.TranslatedDescription != null ? t.TranslatedDescription : t.Description` not work? Or `t.TranslatedDescription ?? t.Description`

Comment: It might, but i really need it in one nhibernate criteria...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of the ISNULL could be expressed like this:

```
// here is the criteria of the "Entity1" and the join to the "Entity2"
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria("Entity1", "table1");
criteria.CreateAlias("Entity2", "table2");

// here we drive the SELECT clause
criteria.SetProjection(
    Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Model"))
        .Add(Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", NHibernateUtil.String
            , Projections.Property("table2.TranslatedDescription")
            , Projections.Property("table1.Description")
            ))
    );

// just a list of object arrays
var list = criteria.List<object[]>();
```

So, what we do here, is a call of the `SqlFunction`. In this case one of the *out-of-the-box* mapped in many Dialects coming with NHibernate *(but we can even extend the dialect with custom ones, an example how to: [Nhibernate count distinct (based on multiple columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725327/))*

Must note, that the JOIN Clause is coming from the mapping. So this `Table2.OriginalDescription = Table1.Description` must come from a mapped relation *many-to-one*

Comment: Thank You. What about if there's no a foreign key? Let's say those two tables have no connection as foreign key... is it possible to have something like that?

Comment: The JOIN is always defined by the mapping, it comes from relationship definition. We can restrict it more... but we cannot create own JOIN and ON clause. That's how the ORM tools work in common... Not the best answer I know... but ... ;)

Comment: :) ... because ... it is not implemented ;) That's all. Simply Creators of (N)Hibernate were looking for least common denominator of the SQL Functions arround the DB engines.... COALESCE was good enough to cover ISNULL ... Hope it helps ;) *(And it is my guess, have to say)*

Comment: Ha. It's really interesting they chose not to implement both. The following article is a good summary as to why you may want to use one over the other...http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull