# Using SQL CONVERT function through nHibernate Criterion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a sql view, in which the data type of every column is `string`, for use with the jquery datatables plugin.

One of the columns contains a uk format date dd/mm/yyyy.

This column needs to remain a string to work with the keystroke filtering of the plugin, however for sorting it needs to be treated as a date.

I am using nhibernate criteria to create the sql query and I want to generate the following order by clause, as this orders the dates correctly

```
order by CONVERT (datetime, DateOfBirth, 103)
```

However in `Nhibernate.Criterion.Projections` there is no `Convert` method. There is `Cast`, but I get the following error due to the fact that it is a UK date format:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type 
resulted in an out-of-range value
```

I have tried also tried the following:

```
 criteria.AddOrder(
             Order.Desc(
     Projections.SqlFunction(
                              "CONVERT",
                               NHibernateUtil.DateTime, 
                               new IProjection[]
                               {
                                 Projections.Property(propNames[orderByColumn]), 
                                 Projections.Property("104")
                               }
                             )
                         )
                   );
```

But I get the following error message:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Current dialect 
       NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect doesn't support the function: CONVERT
```

Can the SQL convert function be used when using `Nhibernate.Criterion` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the setting **104** is not essential, we can get a quick solution: use CAST instead of CONVERT. This SQL Function is built-in in the NHibernate dialects:

```
Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.DateTime
               ,Projections.Property(propNames[orderByColumn]))
```

If the setting *104* is important we can create our own **Dialect**, register the CONVERT function, and use it from then ... forever

Here Andrew Whitaker nicely shows how to

- [Nhibernate count distinct (based on multiple columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725327/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Radim Köhler's answer, here is what I did to fix the problem:

Created a wrapper class to allow me to register the convert function and avoid the dialect exception described in my question:

```
public class MyDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public MyDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("ConvertDate", 
               new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Class, 
                                        "convert(datetime, ?1, 103)"));
    }
}
```

Created a custom projection class to allow me call the new function as a projection in its own right:

```
public static class MyProjections
{
    public static IProjection ConvertDate(params IProjection[] projections)
    {
        return Projections.SqlFunction("ConvertDate", 
                            NHibernateUtil.DateTime, projections);
    }
}
```

Then I check the data type that the string in column represents, then call the ConvertDate method if it is a date

```
 if (propTypes[orderByColumn] == typeof(DateTime))
 {
       criteria.AddOrder(orderIsDesc
           ? Order.Desc(MyProjections.ConvertDate(
                               Projections.Property(propNames[orderByColumn])))
           : Order.Asc(MyProjections.ConvertDate(
                               Projections.Property(propNames[orderByColumn]))));
 }
```

Comment: Great job, sir! Enjoy NHibernate ;)