# NHibernate Formula based property + PostgreSQL interval

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code, nhibernate-configuration

I'm using NHibernate with Mapping by Code and I have a property that is created by this formula.

```
Property(x => x.IsInOverdue,
    mapper => mapper
      .Formula("(SELECT (state_ <> 3 AND invoice_uniqueAlias.duedate_ < NOW()) " + 
               " FROM _invoice AS invoice_uniqueAlias  "+ 
               " WHERE invoice_uniqueAlias.invoice_id = issuedinvoice_key)"));
```

It works perfectly, this sql is inserted as subselect in all queries...

But I would need to add 1 day to invoice_uniqueAlias.duedate_ value. We are using PostgreSQL where the syntax for it is: `invoice_uniqueAlias.duedate_ + interval '1 day'`

But when I put it in mapper.Formula, NHibernate thinks that interval is a name of column and in all queries tries to add table prefix before interval keyword. The generated SQL then looks like:

```
... (SELECT (issuedinvo0_.state_ <> 3 
  AND (invoice_uniqueAlias.duedate_ + (issuedinvo0_.interval '1 day')) < NOW()) ...
```

I tried to put interval keyword in [, `, put statement interval + '1 day' to brackets, but it didn't help. Any suggestions how to handle it correctly in NHibernate or how it is possible to write it in Postgres without using + interval syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, we need NHibernate to treat some words *(**key** words)* as part of the underlying DB engine dialect, we have to just extend it.

One way would be the create custom dialect:

```
public class CustomPostgreDialect : PostgreSQL82Dialect
{
    public CustomPostgreDialect()
    {
        RegisterKeyword("interval");
    }
}
```

And now just use it:

```
<property name="dialect">My.Namespace.CustomPostgreDialect,My.Data</property>
```

Some similar issue - [Using SQL CONVERT function through nHibernate Criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22804798/1679310) (with the similar solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812585/1679310))

Comment: Amazing! ;) Enjoy mighty NHibernate, Jookyn!